# Can't seem to figure out this mysql error. Statement in the body. Any help would be awesome

Tags: mysql

I'm getting the below error with this mysql statement. I'm using PHP 7.2 and can't figure this error out. Any help would be awesome!

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') WHERE review_approved = '0' ORDER BY review_createdate DESC' at line 1

Code:

```
userid) ".
            " INNER JOIN `events` ON (review_id = ev_eventid AND ev_eventid = $eventid  ) ".
           " WHERE review_approved = '1' ORDER BY review_createdate DESC";
```

This is the whole statement:

```
   $query="SELECT * FROM reviews INNER JOIN members ON (review_userid = mem_userid) ". 
         " INNER JOIN events ON (review_id = ev_eventid AND ev_eventid = $eventid ) ". 
         " WHERE review_approved = '1' ORDER BY review_createdate DESC"; // 
   echo $query; 
   $result=mysqli_query($globalMysqlConn,$query) or die(mysqli_error($globalMysqlConn)); 

   while ($mysql_array=mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {
```

Thanks,

Comment: with only that code it is not possible to guess what your query looks like,  have you tried your query direct on phpmyadmin?

Comment: Please post the full SQL statement.

Comment: @Michael in the error you have `WHERE review_approved = '0'` and in the query you provide  is  `WHERE review_approved = '1'`, are you sure is the same query that is producing the error with the one posted ?

Comment: Yes, same one. That's the whole statement and the file generates that error when loading it.

Comment: Hi Michael! Welcome :) I would suggest editing your Question to include the whole sql statement. which I can see you've added in the comments, but may be missed by other users who could help.

Comment: @Michael based on the error produced I think you should check this part `$eventid ` ,  maybe it should be '".$eventid."' ?

Comment: Not sure I follow. Are you stating that I change $eventid to: '".$eventid."'

Comment: @Michael I'm not an `PHP` expert but you can give it a try. I think you should change it

Comment: Whats the value of $eventid?

Comment: What does the output from the `echo $query;` look like? (add it to the question) That may show what could be missing.